# Is there a method to split a string of number in python such as "43","12" .How can we add 4+1 and 3+2

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a method to split a string of number in python such as "43","12" .How can we add 4+1 and 3+2
I hve to perform (4+1)*(3+2) and all the numbers are given in the form of strings

Comment: If you want to implement a calculator, there are two ways. The simple one, use `eval()` function in Python. The more complex and interesting way: [convert the expression to the postfix notation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/Convert-Infix-to-Postfix-Expression) and evaluate it token by token.

Comment: `string_with_number[-1]` will be the last character in the string. `string_with_number[-2]` will be the next-to-last character. If you have a character, you can easily convert it to an integer value. Once you have an integer you can perform your wanted operations on it.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that the numbers are always 2-digits, you can use unpacking:

```
a,b = map(int,"43")
c,d = map(int,"12")
print((a+c)*(b+d)) #25
```

A 1-liner that generalizes to longer numbers is:

```
math.prod(x+y for x,y in zip(map(int,"43"),map(int,"12")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Code :

```py
data = ["43","12"]

def foo(nums):
    result = []
    for vals in zip(*nums):
        result.append(sum(list(map(int, vals))))
    return result

print(foo(data))
```

Result :

```py
[5, 5]
```

Works with other data as well, of course.

lastly, if you want to get the product of the list produced then you could do so by :

```py
data = ["43","12"]

def foo(nums):
    result = []
    for vals in zip(*nums):
        result.append(sum(list(map(int, vals))))
    return result

def product(nums):
    prod = 1
    for each in nums:
        prod *= each
    return prod

print(product(foo(data)))
```

Result :

```
25
```

You could do `math.prod` as well.

Comment: one suggestion: change `iter` to some other variable name, because `iter` is a built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in method for that specific use case, but you could define one yourself, using something along the lines of:

```
a = ["43", "12"]

first_digits = []
second_digits = []

for item in a:
    first_digits.append(int(item[0]))
    second_digits.append(int(item[1]))

print(sum(first_digits) * sum(second_digits))
```